# Zip multiple folder (within directory) to individual files (in a new directory), in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I am trying to zip multiple folders (in a single directory) to their respective files (not in one large zipped file), in a new directory (bearing the same name as the original folder + '.zip').

I am quite new to Python, and after some searching, I came up with the following code (with help from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjH5UFhDnnY&ab_channel=WebDevPro ):

```
import os, zipfile

os.chdir(r"C:\This\Is\An\Example")

for x in os.listdir():
    handle = zipfile.ZipFile(x + ".zip", "w")
    handle.write(x, compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    handle.close()
```

The three problems I am experiencing is, firstly, I am not sure how to set the output/final_product to a new directory. Secondly, the final zipped files are empty - this is because the original file contains other files, and the script changes those files within the original one to the new name (Folder001.zip) - how do I stop the script at the first/main folder, so it does not go into the subfolders. Lastly, the loop seems to go through the folder between up to three times (please refer to the example):

Folder001.zip

Folder001.zip.zip

Folder002.zip

Folder002.zip.zip

Folder002.zip.zip.zip

FolderA.zip

FolderA.zip.zip

FolderA.zip.zip.zip

FolderB.zip

FolderB.zip.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best approach in your case is looping over all the directories in your path and create a `zip` file for each of them, adding only files in these directories (if I understood your problem).

So, the first problem is to find all the directories in your root folder. This can be achieved using `os.walk` on the root folder and looking at the second element of its first output, which is the list of all the folders in your root.

Then, you have to create a zip archive for each of them, containing only the files of these subfolders. Again, you can use `os.walk` on each folder, but this time looking at the third item of its first output, that corresponds to the list of files in that folder.

It would be better to divide the problem into two different subproblems: looping on root folder and creating a zip file from a folder.

The following snippet shows a possible implementation for the function looping over your root folder and creating the path for the output zip files:

```py
def zip_subfolders(input_folder, output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)  # create output folder if it does not exist
    for folder_name in next(os.walk(input_folder))[1]:  # loop over all the folders in your input folder
        zipped_filepath = os.path.join(output_folder, f'{folder_name}.zip')  # create the path for the output zip file for this folder
        curr_folder_path = os.path.join(input_folder, folder_name)  # get the full path of the current folder
        create_zip(curr_folder_path, zipped_filepath)  # create the zip file and put in the right location
```

The following function compresses each subfolder, adding all files present at the first level of the folder:

```py
def create_zip(folder_path, zipped_filepath):
    zip_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_filepath, 'w')  # create a zip file in the required path
    for filename in next(os.walk(folder_path))[2]: # loop over all the file in this folder
        zip_obj.write(
            os.path.join(folder_path, filename),  # get the full path of the current file
            filename,  # file path in the archive: we put all in the root of the archive
            compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        )
    zip_obj.close()
```

Putting all together in a single script:

```py
import os
import zipfile

INPUT_FOLDER = 'to_zip'
OUTPUT_FOLDER = 'zipped'

def create_zip(folder_path, zipped_filepath):
    zip_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_filepath, 'w')  # create a zip file in the required path
    for filename in next(os.walk(folder_path))[2]: # loop over all the file in this folder
        zip_obj.write(
            os.path.join(folder_path, filename),  # get the full path of the current file
            filename,  # file path in the archive: we put all in the root of the archive
            compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        )
    zip_obj.close()

def zip_subfolders(input_folder, output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)  # create output folder if it does not exist
    for folder_name in next(os.walk(input_folder))[1]:  # loop over all the folders in your input folder
        zipped_filepath = os.path.join(output_folder, f'{folder_name}.zip')  # create the path for the output zip file for this folder
        curr_folder_path = os.path.join(input_folder, folder_name)  # get the full path of the current folder
        create_zip(curr_folder_path, zipped_filepath)  # create the zip file and put in the right location

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_subfolders(INPUT_FOLDER, OUTPUT_FOLDER)
```

Comment: Hi @PieCot, this is way overdue and thank you for your assistance.

When I run this code I get the following Exception:
Exception has occurred: StopIteration
exception: no description
  File "C:\..\Folders_Into_Seperate_Zip_Files.py", line 53, in zip_subfolders
    for folder_name in next(os.walk(input_folder))[1]: # loop over all the folders in your input folder
  File "C:\..\Folders_Into_Seperate_Zip_Files.py", line 61, in <module>
    zip_subfolders(inputFolder, outputFolder)

How would you suggest I resolve the Exception?

Comment: Did you set the right path in `INPUT_FOLDER`?

Comment: Thank you, it is almost working now.
The only thing now is that it is trying to zip the `OUTPUT_FOLDER` as well, and as a result, the script does not run to completion (but only if the dir of the Output is different from the Input ).
The output dir code is as follows:
`OUTPUT_FOLDER = "./" +'Zipped' + "/"`, (If I don't do this it zips the folders in the same dir as the unzipped folders), But this is not the end of the world, and the script works, so thank you very much for your assistance, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you do not change the relative paths of the folders, the script is meant to work in the parent directory of both the input folder and the script, i.e.: the root folder must contain the INPUT_FOLDER and the script. Then you have to run the script from the root folder. The script will create a new folder in the root folder with the compressed files.